# HTML input text in 2 colors

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to show some text in red color and the remaining in black inside one html textbox after the on change event or mouse leave event.
Is this possible? if yes how?

Comment: what do you mean by some text??can you please be more specific..

Comment: You need a criteria — based on what criteria that the text should be red or black?

Comment: for e.g: i have a html input text.

value is 'Hello world'

here i want to show 'Hello' in black color and 'world' in red but it should be a text box only.

text color can change while onchange event or lostfocus event.

Comment: I just want to type text i dont mind it is text area, div or paragraph. but it should check the typed text and if it contains 'World' make only World as Red and remaining text as black colored

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can achieve specifically what you're asking for. You can apply CSS to the default value of a text box, but to change the colour of only some of the words within it would require you to use a `<span>`, which you can't within a text box value (i.e. you can type `<span>`, of course, but not apply CSS to it).

If you're happy to have the text within some other element as you imply in a later comment, then that's perfectly doable with very simple CSS using spans within `<p>` or `<div>` elements, as evidenced in the below jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/2DpSX/

Answer (score 1):

Finally I could do this by creating a editable `<div>`

http://jsfiddle.net/EP2dc/

Thanx everyone for the guidance.